# TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable during reading data

Tags: python, typeerror, importdata

I'm pretty new importing data and I´m trying to make def that reads in the presented order. The error is in the fuction, not in the data.

```py
def read_eos(filename: str, order: dict[str, int] = {"density": 0, "pressure": 1, 
    "energy_density": 2}):
  
    # Paths to files
    current_dir = os.getcwd()
    INPUT_PATH = os.path.join(current_dir, "input")

    in_eos = np.loadtxt(os.path.join(INPUT_PATH, filename))
    eos = np.zeros(in_eos.shape)

    # Density
    eos[:, 0] = in_eos[:, order["density"]]
    eos[:, 1] = in_eos[:, order["pressure"]]
    eos[:, 2] = in_eos[:, order["energy_density"]]

    return eos
```

Comment: It would help to (1) have a sample input to test this function, so that you'd have at least something halfway resembling a minimal reproducible example (emphasis on the *reproducible* part), and (2) to have a traceback, not just the last error message that you got.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/santiagopendonminguillon/Desktop/Sin título4.py", line 21, in <module>
    def read_eos(filename: int, order: dict[int, int] = {"density": 0, "pressure": 1, "energy_density": 2}):

TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Add the traceback to your original post. Don't put it in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem is right in the type hint of one of your function parameters: `dict[str, int]`. As far as Python is concerned, `[str, int]` is a *subscript* of the type `dict`, but `dict` can't accept that subscript, hence your error message.

The fix is fairly simple. First, if you haven't done so already, add the following import statement above your function definition:

```py
from typing import Dict
```

Then, change `dict[str, int]` to `Dict[str, int]`.